# Ubuntu server not using localhost IP for internal communication

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ip, localhost, amavis

I am using Ubuntu Server 13.04 on my mail system.
I am just setting the Postfix and Amavis.
In every config for communication I am using 127.0.0.1 as IP address to pass mails to amavis.
When I look to the logs its still trying to connect to Amavis with my eth0 IP address which is connected to the internet. I dont want to allow this IP address in the configs.
Is there any way how to tell Ubuntu to use the 127.0.0.1 instead of my internet IP address?
I dont know why this is happening.
Thank you.

**Edit:** More info

This is what I set in postfix **main.cf**:

```
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

and **master.cf**:

```
127.0.0.1:10025  inet  n  -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
```

Also this is what I have in **/etc/amavis/conf.d/50-user**:

```
@inet_acl = qw( 127.0.0.1 );
```

But when I try to receive a mail, in the logs there is:

```
 amavis[29607]: () (!)DENIED ACCESS from IP 1.2.3.4, policy bank ''
```

where 1.2.3.4 is my IP address of eth0 interface.. Why its not accessing it with 127.0.0.1 but with eth0 IP address? I think I am missing something and this might be just how it works.. I am just asking if there is any explanation or possibility to change this. Because now I always have to add my IP address to `inet_acl` and the subnet `mynetworks`.. Thanks.

Comment: Show us exactly what is happening and exactly what you have configured.

Comment: I have just added more info.. Hope it will make more sense what I mean.. Thank you for the reply @MichaelHampton

Answer (score 0):

Check for inet_interfaces option in Postfix.
I suppose Postfix should explicitly bind 127.0.0.1 to use in output communications.

FYI: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-receive-mail-on-specific-network-interfaces/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Anyway since I have to use both 127.0.0.1 and my inet address its not gonna make any change.. I have tried it and its doing still the same.